# D-separation in a Bayesian Network

Tags: self-study, bayesian, graphical-model, bayesian-network

[image]

The above question asks to see if Radio is D-Separated from Petrol given certain evidence.

1. For evidence (i), why would this mean D-Separation? If Battery is true, we have a inactive triple. If Starts were true, however, then this would cause a active triple. Doesn't this active triple mean Radio and Petrol are not D-Separated? Or is the fact that a inactive triple exists in the path enough for them to be D-Separated?
2. I assume for this same reason, evidence (ii) also shows D-Separation? I assume it is because it doesn't matter whether Battery or true/false. As long as it is observed, it creates a inactive triple, which proves D-Separation?
3. Why is evidence (iii) showing no D-Separation? Is it simply because a active triple exists now that Battery is unknown? Or is there more to it than that?
4. Why is evidence (iv) showing no D-Separation? Is it due to the same reason as (iii)?

Comment: Ah, I did not know that. In that case, I assume true and false do mean observed and not observed. The question I showed above was a little ambiguous about that fact.

Comment: Oh sorry got a little confused. Now that I think about it, doesn't the fact a variable can be defined as True or False mean it is observed? In this case, everything mentioned is observed?

Comment: Please add the [self-study] tag & read its wiki.

Comment: Added the requested tag.

Comment: Just to clarify, the answers to each question in the image are from the answer sheet and not my own. The reason I am asking the above questions is to clarify if my understanding of how to reach those answers is correct.

Answer (score 0):

i) and ii) Radio and Petrol are independent given Battery is observed because any path between Radio and Petrol goes through Battery and Battery is observed (therefore the path is bloqued).

iii) Given starts  is observed (and there is a Vstructure Ignition->Starts<-Petrol) then Radio and Petrol ARE not conditionally independent given Starts since there is a path that goes from Radio to petrol through Start (the path is enabled by the fact that Start is observed).

iv) they are not conditionally independent since Moves is a descendant of Starts and therefore it allows the path through the V-structure Ignition->Starts<-Petrol.

Some sources that might help you:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aA-gTNxy1rw

http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/d-sep.html

Comment: Wait but the answer to ii specifically says that it is independent.